# Web application architecture design - HTML/CSS/JS frontend + REST Backend

Tags: html, rest, architecture

I have some experience developing websites, but none with proper web applications.

But this time I'm creating more of a web application, my server will surely handle API calls from a mobile app (iPhone/Android/MeeGo (...or not)) or even from third party clients.

So I'm thinking, is it really necessary that the "website" --the frontend part of my application using HTML (5)/CSS (3) and JS--interacts with my backend in a different way than my other "frontends"?

Am I thinking wrong? I think this is a common problem, and I need some experimented advices on that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is this tagged django?

Comment: @weberc2 Because he is "mainly using the Django framework".

Comment: @EpicDavi I mainly use Linux. Doesn't mean I use that tag for every question I ask.

Comment: @weberc2 Linux isn't related to the question. Django is a framework that can be used to make web applications (such as the one he is trying to make here). He is familiar with Django and therefore it would be beneficial to him if his goals could be accomplished using it to save time and effort.

Comment: @EpicDavi Nothing in the question nor the accepted answer pertains to Django (except where he said he uses Django). His question pertains very generally to web application architecture. It doesn't matter if he uses Django or Rails or PHP or etc. Anything that can talk HTTP would suffice. 100% irrelevant.

Comment: @weberc2 The accepted answer should have no effect on the tags, as they were tagged at the creation of the question. I would say that my earlier points still stand. His question is whether he is thinking correctly in that his new frontend should interact with the backend in a different way than his other frontends do (presumably in Django). Although we may never know the real reason OP decided to tag this Django, I have provided you with my best explanation, and your choice to accept it is up to you.

Comment: @EpicDavi the lack of mention of django in the accepted answer is further evidence that it's unrelated to the topic. Your points don't support your argument.

Comment: @weberc2 I am not arguing whether or not Django is related to the question. I am answering your question on why it is tagged. Furthermore, as I stated earlier, tags are not necessarily indicative of the answers given. The accepted answer points out Twitter, Scala, and Rails (similar in many ways to Django) which, in your reasoning, are off-topic. If the accepted answer (possibly a person drawn from the Django tag) was "The way you were doing your websites previously was correct." then Django could be very relevant in the context of the question.

Comment: @EpicDavi "I am not arguing whether or not Django is related to the question. I am answering your question on why it is tagged." I know. I'm saying it shouldn't be tagged because it is unrelated. I don't know how to make this simpler.

"Furthermore, as I stated earlier, tags are not necessarily indicative of the answers given." <- I didn't say anything about tags being indicative of answers given. If the answer had mentioned Django, it would be indicative of the appropriateness of the tag. Its absence might not *prove* that the tag is bad, but it is evident of that conclusion.

Comment: @EpicDavi "The accepted answer points out Twitter, Scala, and Rails (similar in many ways to Django) which, in your reasoning, are off-topic." <- Correct. These are other great examples of tags that make no sense for this question. But they weren't added as tags, they're providing context to an answer, and these words are entirely appropriate for that purpose.

Comment: @EpicDavi "If the accepted answer (possibly a person drawn from the Django tag) was "The way you were doing your websites previously was correct." then Django could be very relevant in the context of the question." <- but it's not, so let's not go down that highly irrelevant rabbit hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually No. You're thinking it the right way. You can Javascript to interact with your Rest API, so you can focus only on writing a scalable API, and the UI.
That's the approach taken by Twitter. Their web site, is a Rails application that uses the twitter API, written mostly in Scala, and uses by the hundreds of twitter clients out there, whether mobile or desktop app.